# Can I use one view controller to handle multiple views in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am making an app with a tab bar which will display three different timers.  The three timers are almost identical aside from the time and a few labels.  Currently I am using 3 view controllers on my story board for the timers which use the same class, and embedding these into a tab bar view controller.  Is there a way I can have one view controller and then programmatically use it three times in the tab bar view controller?  Is this even a good path to go down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A view can only have one parent so you need three separate view instances to populate the three tabs. And since a view controller only has one view, each of the view instances in the three tabs needs its own view controller instance.

You can have one view controller class with three instances of that view controller, but you can't use one view controller instance and its one view instance to populate three tabs.

Comment: Thanks, so it sounds like my current implementation may be the best way to go.  It just seemed bad to copy and paste view controllers and then link them to the same class.

Comment: It would be far worse to make those copies and assign them to three different view controller classes that were just copies of each other.